# determining whether a binary relation of a power set is reflexive, symmetric and transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

[image]

Please ignore the red asterisk.

I believe that it is reflexive when mapping out single elements within the power set, each single element will be related to itself.

I believe that it is symmetric since the parameter |A ∩ B| ≥ 2 has been stated, if there was no parameter I don't think that it would be symmetric.

I also believe that R is an equivalence relation since it holds the entire power set ranging from 1 to 50, so if I were to map it out everything would be related to everything.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: **Hints:** *Reflexive:* the empty set is a subset of every set.  *Symmetric:* $|A\cap B|=|B\cap A|$.  *Transitive:* $\{1,2\}$ is related to $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is further related to other things too...

Comment: "Please ignore the red asterisk": then why include it?

Comment: Because it was a screenshotted image.  You should type it yourself so that your question is more easily searchable allowing people who can answer easier time finding it as well as other people with similar questions to find it more easily, also allowing the system to detect possible duplicates and related questions.  [Visit this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Just in case if it is the power set which is causing you the issues, remember that $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb X)=\{X~:~X\subseteq\Bbb X\}$, that is to say the powerset of a set is the set of all subsets of that set.  $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,\dots,50\})=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\dots,\{50\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\dots,\{49,50\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\dots,\dots,\{1,2,\dots,50\}\}$

Comment: Another possible reason why you are making mistakes is that you misunderstood the relation. Rephrased "two sets are said to be 'related' iff they have at least two elements in common (and not related if they have fewer than two in common)" so for example $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is related to $\{1,2,3,6,7\}$ because they share at least two elements in common (*namely $1,2,$ and $3$*), but $\{1,2\}$ is not related to $\{3,4\}$ because they share fewer than two elements in common (*in fact they share no elements in common*).

Answer (score 1):

The relation is not reflexive because {1}R{1}
is not possible since it has only one element.

Clearly it is symmetric.

It is not transitive.  Create an example that shows it isn't.